# Preencher linha do StringGrid com variável de N caracteres

Tags: delphi-7

Preencher linha do StringGrid com variável de N caracteres

Saudações a todos

estou usando este código só para jogar as letras sem valores no stringgrid

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  t: TStringList;
  i:integer;
begin
 t := TStringList.create; // cria uma classe
 t.text := stringReplace(Edit1.Text, '|', #13,[rfReplaceAll]);//substitui | por quebra de linha
  for i := 0 to Pred(t.Count) do
      StringGrid1.cells[i+1,2]:=t[i]; // joga todos elementos do edit na stringgrid 
                                      //i+1 para prencher a partir da coluna 2
  t.free; //  destruir a classe
end;
```

seria possível jogar uma varivel desconhecida em nº caracteres em apenas uma linha do StringGrid, sabendo que cada caractere tem um valor, que corresponde a quantidade de colunas que ocupará, usando o TStringList?

xdyz      a string variável é composta N caracteres 
1342     ( cada caractere da string tem um valor e cada uma delas corrresponde a uma quantidade colunas )

para:

caractere x =  1 células  [ x ]

caractere d =  3 células  [ d ] [ d ][ d ]

caractere y =  4 células  [ y] [ y ][ y ][ y ]

caractere z =  2 células  [ z] [ z ]

............

resultado final em uma única linha da StringGrid para essa várivel de 4 caracteres

[ x ][ d ][ d ][ d ][ y] [ y ][ y ][ y ][ z] [ z ]  .........

Comment: O jeito mais _simples_ seria criar uma `matriz` de 2 colunas, armazenando o caractere e o seu valor, e para preencher a `StringGrid`, percorrer a string e checar cada caractere na matriz, após achar o caractere, preencher a `StringGrid` x vezes dependendo do valor encontrado, e passar pro próximo.

Comment: olá Pedro Roweder,  poderia dar um exemplo, porque preciso jogar as informações pra ficar numa única linha do stringgrid

Answer (score 0):

Montei algo pra você ter uma ideia, espero que ajude.

```
const
  Letras  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  Numeros = '123456789';
var
  oSLDados, oSLGrid: TStringList;
  iContValor, iContSort, nValor, iSort, iIncGrid : Integer;
  sCaracteres: String;
begin      
  nValor   := StrToIntDef(VALOR DIGITADO NO EDIT,0);
  oSLDados := TStringList.Create;
  oSLGrid  := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //PERCORRER O N VALOR PARA SORTEAR OS NUMEROS
    for iContValor := 0 to nValor-1 do
    begin
      sCaracteres := '';
      iSort       := StrToIntDef(Numeros[Random(Length(Numeros))],0);
      for iContSort := 0 to iSort-1 do
      begin
        if iContSort <> iSort-1 then
          sCaracteres := sCaracteres+Trim(Letras[Random(Length(Letras))])+';'
        else
          sCaracteres := sCaracteres+Trim(Letras[Random(Length(Letras))]);
      end;
      oSLDados.Add(sCaracteres);
    end;

    //PERCORRE STRINGLIST E PREENCHE A STRINGGRID
    iIncGrid := 1;
    for iContValor := 0 to oSLDados.Count-1 do
    begin
      oSLGrid.AddStrings(oSLDados);
      oSLGrid.Delimiter       := ';';
      oSLGrid.StrictDelimiter := True;
      oSLGrid.DelimitedText   := oSLDados.Strings[iContValor];

      for iContSort := 0 to oSLGrid.Count-1 do
      begin
        StringGrid1.Cells[iIncGrid,0] := oSLGrid.Strings[iContSort];
        Inc(iIncGrid);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(oSLDados);
    FreeAndNil(oSLGrid);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Jefferson Rudolf que bacana agradecido  mesmo a você,       estou usando o delphi 7 ele não reconhece essa linha de instrução (StrictDelimiter)        da linha   oSLGrid.StrictDelimiter := True;      ai o programa  para ali e não copila no delphi 7 e nem executa